# what function or loop do I have to use to average the matrix?

Tags: matlab, matrix, sum, average

I want to find the average of all the matrix:

Data=(Data{1}+......+Data{n})/n)
where Data{n} is a matrix of m*n..

Thank you sooo much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you convert your cell array into a 3D array, then you can take the average, like this:

```
tmp = cat(3,Data{:}); %# catenates the data, so that it becomes a m*n*z (or m*1*n)
averageData = mean(tmp,3); %# takes average along 3rd dimension
```

Note: if you get memory problems this way, and if you don't need to keep the variable `Data` around, you can replace `tmp` with `Data` and all will work fine.

Alternatively, if `Data` is simply a m*n numeric array

```
averageData = mean(Data,2);
```

Answer (score 1):

If your cell array is really big, you might want to keep away from the above solution because of its memory usage. I'd then suggest using the utility `mtimesx` which is available from Matlab Central, [here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/25977-mtimesx-fast-matrix-multiply-with-multi-dimensional-support).

```
N = length(Data);
b = cell(N,1);
b(:) = {1};
averageData = mtimesx(Data,b)/N;
```

In the above example, I assumed that Data is a line-shaped cell array. I have never used personally `mtimesx`, this solution comes from [there](http://www.mathworks.de/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/282327), where timing issues are also discussed.

Hope this helps.

A.